# How to return entity Id from c sharp API to angular 9?

Tags: c#, angular

I have a function that inserts data into database user in the backend:

```
    public async Task <int> CreateOrEdit(UserDto input)
    {
        if (input.Id == null)
        {
            return await Create(input);

        }
        else
        {
            await Update(input);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

The implementation of the method Create is as below:

```
    protected virtual async Task<int> Create(UserDto input)
    {   // this does mapping using auto mapper
        var users = ObjectMapper.Map<UserManagement>(input);

        return  await _userRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(users);
    }
```

I have used InsertAndGetIdAsync, which should add and return the Id of the entity.

Now in my client application - typescript:

```
userId : any;
save(): void {
this.saving = true;
this._userServiceProxy.createOrEdit(this.users)
.pipe(finalize(() => { this.saving = false; this.userId = this.users.id}))
.subscribe(() => {
this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
this.close();
this.modalSave.emit(null);
alert(this.userId);
});
}
```

I have created a global variable userId, and tried to retrieve it in the pipe. I have also set an alert to test if it is being returned but it returns blank. I know that there is the http.get method to retrieve data but in my case, I have to return the userId being created immediately after it is saved.
Does anyone know how to achieve this and what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: `this.userId = this.users.id`guessing this is the part where you expect the userId to be available. I can't see any code that would write the http response to to `this.users.id` so why do you expect the userId to be available there? Next we don't know any details of your `createOrEdit(user)` method, so I don't know what happens there with your http response that holds the new userId.

Comment: I am using asp.net zero framework, and it seems that the values should be returned under subscribe. Lets assume method create or update returns integer value 99. I tried to modify it as below, but it still does not work:                                                               
    userId : any;
     save(): void {
        this.saving = true;
        this._userServiceProxy.createOrEdit(this.users).subscribe((response : any) => {
            this.userId  = response.result;
            console.log(this.userId );
        });

Comment: I don't know this framework. But I'd suggest to do debug like so: a) Look at your browsers dev tools > network and check if you send the expected request and you get the expected response. Then set a breakpoint inside you subscribe method. this should be the correct place where you should see your response. Look what exactly you have in response variable. If you can't solve it, please post all details of all steps mentioned.